# NewtonSoft.Json is returning null for all

Tags: json, .net-core, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I am using `Microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.newtonsoftjson`(5.0.2) for JSON, I opted for this instead of System.Text.Json, because in latter one I could not find an option to ignore the loop.

When I try to de-serialize to an Object, it returns null for all properties...

```
[DataContract]
public class UserDefinition
{
    public UserDefinition();

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string EmailId { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
    public List<string> AuthKey { get; set; }
    public IList<SiteDefinition> AuthBranches { get; set; }
}
```

Data that needs to be Deserialize

[image: DataJson]

Code used for deserialization...

```
ud = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserDefinition>(erpResponse);
```

result

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because of the attribute you've applied to your class:

```
[DataContract]
```

When this is present, Json.net will only consider properties that are attributed with `[DataMember]`. Since you didn't add this attribute to any of the properties, they're all ignored.

You have two solutions:

1. Remove `[DataContract]` from your class
2. Add `[DataMember]` to all relevant properties